# How I can call showinfowindow() in a marker within cluster manager?

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm working with markers in a cluster (google maps), I have no problem in showing an info window when calling the onclick method.
The problem is that I can't find how to use the method showInfoWindow() as I do on a marker to open the info without giving click.

When I use a marker

```
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(position)
                    .snippet(info));
```

then I call

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

how I can do the same with a marker (ClusterItem) that is on the map within the cluster manager?

```
MarkCluster cluster = new MarkCluster(Lat, Lon, info);
mClusterManager.addItem(cluster);
```

It is the marker that I want to show infoWindow
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get a reference to a marker that has been added to a map by the ClusterRenderer? (i.e. get a reference to a marker that has been added after you zoom in on a cluster?)

Comment: Yes, if I get the reference i'll can call the infowindow. I have been reading and searching for but can not find the way.

Comment: Should be able to use `mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers()`, but you'll need to go through the list to get the Marker reference you're looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, its what I did to get references to map markers when using clustering:

When you create a `ClusterManager` it always creates and uses an instance of the `DefaultClusterRenderer` if you don't call the `.setRenderer()` method and pass it an instance of your own `ClusterRenderer` implementation. If you are letting the `ClusterManager` create its own `DefaultClusterRenderer` the key is to add it explicitly so that you can keep a reference to it (because the `ClusterManager` has no getter method so you can get a reference to the `ClusterRenderer` its using):

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ClusterItem>(getActivity(), mMap);
mRenderer = new DefaultClusterRenderer(getActivity(), mMap, mClusterManager); 
mClusterManager.setRenderer(mRenderer); 
mClusterManager.addItem(ClusterItem);
```

Then when you need access to a marker pass the `ClusterRenderer` the `ClusterItem` associated with the marker. The `ClusterItem` you use to find the marker will be the `ClusterItem` you passed to the `ClusterManager` to add the marker to the cluster originally:

```
Marker marker = mRenderer.getMarker(ClusterItem);
if(marker != null){
    marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```

The `Marker` object will be null if the marker has not been rendered on the map yet so be sure to check that the marker object is not null before using it.

If you are certain the marker has been placed on the map when you call `.getMarker()` and marker is still null then override the `.equals()` method
in the object use to implement the `ClusterItem` Interface to make sure you can find the correct `ClusterItem` object held by the renderer.

Comment: Thanks you. This is exactly what I was looking for. My mistake was that I was looking at the ClusterManager.. I just want to emphasize that if not yet to rendering (mRenderer), the marker always return null.
So once the method onClusterItemRendered is executed, I get the marker

Comment: I recently had this same problem so I'm glad I was able to help you out.